# if i do loop in onbindView of adapter class android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Chapter chapter = chapters.get(position);
        String toDay = chapter.chapterName + "  " + chapter.month + "  " + chapter.year;

if (arr!=null) {
    for (String s : arr) {
        if (toDay.equals(s)) {
            holder.linear.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.subscripti);
        }
    }
}
```

if i do  loop in onbindView  of adapter class the loop responce every time printing  when try to scroll schoing and recyclerview scrolling not smoothing android

Comment: What do you want to do? Why do you iterate over arr?

Comment: for example in arr have [12  january  2019,14  january 2019] iam checking values in today string values if valus found changing the background color

Answer (score 0):

Time Complexity of Array is O(n) and HashSet is O(1) so it's better to use HashSet in this scenario.
You can do something like this:
1- Add all days in a HashSet:

```
Set<String> days = new HashSet<>();
days.add("12 january 2019");
days.add("14 january 2019");
```

2- Then pas it to your addapter and check if this Hashset contains current day or not

```
if(days.contains(today)){
   // Do what you want     
}
```